# terser-webpack-plugin generates different output in another machine

Tags: webpack

i'm new to front end, so trying to explain the problem.

The Gruntfile is using terser-webpack-plugin 4.8.0.
webpack 4.46.0.
We use "Gruntfile compile" to generate output.js.

I have a clean folder, fresh git clone of the source, generates output.js.
Consume it in front end code, it's causing errors doesn't make sense, e.g. sth. like "e is not a function"

Now coworker does the same thing, run it in the same environment, everything works fine. Both his and mine are MacOS.

Where should i start debug this pls ?

Comment: What's the result of running `node -v` in the console on both machines? The same, or different?

Comment: his node 12.12.0, mine 12.13.1

Comment: I'd recommend everyone use the same exact version if possible. You could both try upgrading to `12.21.0`. It might not be the issue, but it's pretty foundational, especially if there's some bug in one of your versions.

Comment: ok, do u think different webpack version or other packages could cause problem ？

Comment: Presumably you have a `yarn.lock` or maybe an npm shrinkwrap file, right? If you have one of those, then the packages installed should be virtually identical, if not exactly identical.

Comment: we do have yarn.lock, that's why it's so confusing to me.

Comment: But did you both upgrade your Node versions?